# Applying the substitution theorem in integrals when the substitution function is not $C^1$.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

I was given a simple problem of finding $\int_1^2 \frac{\sqrt{t-1}}{t}dt$. Educated in Physics as I am, I jumped right in and substituted $u^2 = t-1$, $2udu =dt$ and simplified the integral to an immediately solvable one. However, now that I have to pay attention to the theorems that I'm actually using, my book says that in order to be able to use the substitution theorem you need in this case $u$ to be continuous and have a continuous derivative, and in this case $u'$ is not continuous (not even defined!) in $1$. My first idea was to use another theorem I have that says that if $f$ is bounded in $[a,b]$ and is integrable in $[c,b]$ for all $c \in (a,b)$, then $f$ is integrable in $[a,b]$ and I can find the integral as a limit, that would allow me to circumvent the point $x=1$, but that seems too complicated for a simple problem and I was wondering if there wasn't an easier way to go about it.

Comment: What is the title of  the book and page ? Thanks

Comment: @LostInSpace Well, the textbook we're using is in Spanish, but if you want to check it out anyways its Cálculo infinitesimal de una variable by Juan de Burgos, page 322

Comment: Thank you Delta

Comment: Have you got a misprint there? As written the integral is purely imaginary. I get $i\left(2-\frac{\pi}2\right)$.

Comment: @user5713492 you're absolutely right, it should be $\frac{\sqrt{t-1}}{t}$. Thanks for telling me, fixed it in the original.

Answer (score 2):

Why not treat it like any other "problem integral" and start with 
$$  \lim_{L \rightarrow 1^+} \int_L^2 \frac{\sqrt{1-t}}{t} \,\mathrm{d}t  $$

Comment: This is definitely one of the possibilities I was considering, but I thought there must be an easier way. It's not like the function itself is divergent in any point in the interval, it's just that the derivative of the particular substitution function I'm using is. If there's no other way, I'm definitely doing this though.